# Reset colors back to default

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

With some code, I used to derive a histogram with different colors per bar:

[image: histogram]

When I use the same code now, I get this:

[image]

How do I change it back to being colorful?

I am using Visual Studio Code (if that matters) and my code looks something like this:

```py
pd.Series([1,7,9,8,5], index=[1,2,3,4,5]).plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please post your code as a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @bcosta12: That is kind of the problem: I cannot reproduce it! I posted some code to work with though. The question could be rephrased to: How to color each bar differently without explicitly specifying the colors?